# Need help with Data Security requirement

Tags: profile, security, data, owd

Below is my requirement:
There are multiple programs within the org and I have this requirement.

Part 1: Profile A should only be able to see Program A data (Accounts, Customers, etc..)
Part 2: Profile B should be able to see all client's data except Program A data.

I have been able to complete Part 1 by marking the OWD of all the required objects private and creating a new sharing rule on each of those objects to extend access to a group of users who are part of Profile A. The criteria filters only Program A data and extends access to Group A.

For Part 2, I am not sure which Salesforce feature I can use to restrict access in the same way I extended access using sharing settings in Part 1.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.
I have been struggling on this for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share "all but this group's" data. You would need to build a group for profile A records, then a second group for all records except profile A's data, and share it with profile B via another group. This means you probably need three groups altogether.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is what I would have to do from what you are saying:

There are 11 objects I need to create new sharing settings for and 3 programs.

So 3 public groups and 33 new sharing settings.

Comment: @BabbarSiddiq If that's what you need to do, yes.